# Ui-grid with uib-popover as a cellTemplate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I'm trying to use a uib-popover from ui-bootstrap in the ui-grid, but when I click in the popover, the "click" events goes to my grid. I set a Plunker with this problem: https://next.plnkr.co/plunk/aFbYIYsKAD3puSt6

The first column (Name) is the one with the cellTemplate.
If you click in the icon, a popover will appear, and the grid doesn't allow you to click in the Input that I put there, only if you click in the Label, but even so, it's still pretty buggy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it.
It was pretty simple actually, you just need to set the "allowCellFocus" to false in the colDef of the grid

Updated Plunker:
https://next.plnkr.co/plunk/FSZXUViAhu8CMWaT